# In polars, when would you use rolling_mean vs groupby_rolling?

Tags: python-polars

It is not 100% clear to me when to use rolling_mean and when to use groupby_rolling in polars.  For example, you can't pass a min_periods in groupby_rolling, but you can in rolling_mean.

When should you use rolling_mean and when should you use groupby_rolling in polars?